# 3D mammogram database for image processing

Tags: image-processing

I am currently working in the field of breast cancer. I have searched a lot to get the database for the 3D mammograms (DBT). 
Please do help me in finding a solution for me from where I can get a database.

Thank you.

Comment: if there is anything decent you would find it online using a websearch like google. that's one of many reasons why questions like yours are off-topic

Comment: This is something which is not available in simple search. 3D mammogram dataset is not available in public when I searched.